# How to deserilaze an array of object in webservice.?

Tags: web-services

I'm new at using web services and i couldn't find any suitable tutorial for deserializing array of object in the client side.

I've written a client that calling a method of the web service that returning an array of object. but when i run my client i get an exception that i think it is related to my deserializer code.

I'm getting the below error ,

```
**Error :** SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
```

I'll be glad if someone can help me,

Thanks
Arun.

Comment: Are you trying to de-serialize using .Net?